# Linking with newlib: undefined reference to memcpy

Tags: arm, ld, newlib, bare-metal

I'm trying to build an arm boot loader, and it's relying on newlib to supply some system calls (like memcpy).

When I run:

```
arm-elf-ld -static -L /usr/arm-elf/lib/thumb/ -lc -nostdlib -nostartfile -Map=loader.map --cref -T loader.lds --gc-sections -Ttext 0x000000 -n -o loader.elf start.o _udivsi3.o _umodsi3.o main.o util.o gpio.o spi.o flashatmel.o flashjedec.o image.o time.o clock.o led.o register.o sdram.o
```

I get the following:

```
 flashatmel.o flashjedec.o image.o time.o clock.o led.o register.o sdram.o            
 main.o: In function `TtyPutConfiguration':
/home/shawn/projects/netbridge-fx/loader/main.c:19: undefined reference to `memcpy'
main.o: In function `main':
/home/shawn/projects/netbridge-fx/loader/main.c:135: undefined reference to   `__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi'
/home/shawn/projects/netbridge-fx/loader/main.c:145: undefined reference to `__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi'
/home/shawn/projects/netbridge-fx/loader/main.c:155: undefined reference to `__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi'
/home/shawn/projects/netbridge-fx/loader/main.c:165: undefined reference to `__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi'
gpio.o: In function `GpioTest':
/home/shawn/projects/netbridge-fx/loader/gpio.c:139: undefined reference to `__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi'
```

For now, I'm attacking the memcpy, and hoping the others follow. When I run `nm /usr/arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a` (which, I believe, is the newlib version of libc), it shows:

```
lib_a-memcpy.o:
00000010 N $d
00000000 t $t
00000001 T memcpy
```

So, that shows that memcpy is defined in the library.

I ran `strace` on the `ld` command above to make sure it's actually looking at that file, and indeed, it is.

What am I missing here? Why is it complaining about an undefined memcpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks fishy:

```
-lc -nostdlibs
```

I think -nostdlibs is canceling out -lc.  Try linking libc.a directly and see what happens.

While you're at it, I see you're linking in some intrinsic implementations (like _udivsi3.o).  Try linking with libgcc.a, it should have definitions for all of the intrinsics you need.

Comment: Linking the file directly worked, although I'm still not sure why `-lc` combined with `-L` doesn't work, even without `-nostdlib`. Any ideas?